# How to close angular dropdown by clicking on target?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I using this [tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/angularjs/tutorial/create-dropdown-control) for my angular dropdown list.

Now dropdown close when you click on dropdown-list__item or any area around dropdown-container.

I need add code for **close** dropdown list by cliking on div.dropdown-display.

```
<div class="dropdown-container" ng-class="{ show: listVisible }">
<div class="dropdown-display" ng-click="show();" ng-class="{ clicked: listVisible }">
    <span ng-if="!isPlaceholder">{{display}}</span>
    <span class="placeholder" ng-if="isPlaceholder">{{placeholder}}</span>
    <i class="dropdown__arrow"></i>
</div>
<div class="dropdown-list">
    <div>
        <div class="dropdown-list__item" ng-repeat="item in list" ng-click="select(item)" ng-class="{ selected: isSelected(item) }">
            <span class="dropdown-list__item__text">{{property !== undefined ? item[property] : item}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and js code for this template

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
    angular.element(document).on("click", function(e) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("documentClicked", angular.element(e.target));
     });
});

app.directive("dropdown", function($rootScope) {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "templates/dropdown.html",
    scope: {
        placeholder: "@",
        list: "=",
        selected: "=",
        property: "@"
    },
    link: function(scope) {
        scope.listVisible = false;
        scope.isPlaceholder = true;

        scope.select = function(item) {
            scope.isPlaceholder = false;
            scope.selected = item;
        };

        scope.isSelected = function(item) {
            return item[scope.property] === scope.selected[scope.property];
        };

        scope.show = function() {
            scope.listVisible = true;
        };

        $rootScope.$on("documentClicked", function(inner, target) {
            console.log($(target[0]).is(".dropdown-display.clicked") || $(target[0]).parents(".dropdown-display.clicked").length > 0);
            if (!$(target[0]).is(".dropdown-display.clicked") && !$(target[0]).parents(".dropdown-display.clicked").length > 0)
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.listVisible = false;
                });
        });

        scope.$watch("selected", function(value) {
            scope.isPlaceholder = scope.selected[scope.property] === undefined;
            scope.display = scope.selected[scope.property];
        });
    }
}
});
```